apk ionic no me conecta a mi apirest local
Tengo mi aplicación desarrollada en ionic, que se conecta a un apirest que tengo en local. Cuando estoy en el navegador funciona, pero cuando ejecuto el apk no se conecta a mi url del apirest ¿Que puede ser?

En android studio tengo el archivo network-security-config.xml

Y en el AndroidManifest.xml tengo android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"



Y en el celular que esta conectado a la misma red, se genera un error ¿Que puede estar pasando?

No te estara faltando <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> en el manifest...

Tengo el
" 

"

Las últimas versiones de android de forma predeterminada no aceptan conexiones a urls no cifradas, es decir http://, en todas tus conexiones deberías usar https://.
Para permitir conexiones a internet no cifradas deberías usar:
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />

Este es un ejemplo de un config.xml
  <access origin="*" />
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
        <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
    </edit-config>
    <allow-navigation href="*" />


No logro hacer que la aplicación se conecte al backen local con HTTP, coloco la configuración que me dices. Pero aun asi no se conecta
